# Using a SSL certificate on an Android device (HTML 5 Chrome application)

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

We are creating a browser based HTML5 application targeted for Android devices through the Chrome browser.  Security is a chief concern and beyond userid/password requirements, the company also desires to ensure each user has a proper SSL certificate installed before granting access.

Does this even make sense, and if so, can someone provide some resources where I can research this further?

I always thought the cert was stored on the server to secure a session between itself and a client.  But I am not aware of the browser somehow providing an installed cert to a server that ensures it is a valid client.

Comment: You can install a certificate on a brower (at least a desktop browser) but this sort of defeats the point.  Then someone could forge the certificate and gain access.  That's why you use SSL authorizing certificates that are already included in the browser.  Self signed certificates always cause issues anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL communications can involve certificates installed to both the client and server.  An IIS website can be configured to require a client side certificate is installed.

Regarding Android, current versions do not support leveraging an installed client side certificate through the browser.  This thread is tracking this particular feature.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11231#c107

Comment: Haven't tried it out myself, but this is supposably fixed now.